# How to control the flexbox size in mui v5?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

Currently I have a code directly copying from mui v5 Card example, and I realized that the size of my flexbox is different from the mui example.

The mui example look like below. The image is pushed to the right side.

[image]

for me, the image remained in the middle. So I have applied a border to visualize the flexbox size, and I realized that the flexbox of my CardMedia does not follow his parent `Card` component. It look like this:
[image]

This is the code:

```
        <Card sx={{ display: 'flex', border: 4 }}>
          <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <CardContent sx={{ flex: '1 0 auto' }}>
              <Typography component="div" variant="h5">
                Live From Space
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="text.secondary" component="div">
                Mac Miller
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', pl: 1, pb: 1 }}>
              <IconButton aria-label="previous">
                {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <SkipNextIcon /> : <SkipPreviousIcon />}
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton aria-label="play/pause">
                <PlayArrowIcon sx={{ height: 38, width: 38 }} />
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton aria-label="next">
                {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <SkipPreviousIcon /> : <SkipNextIcon />}
              </IconButton>
            </Box>
          </Box>
          <CardMedia component="img" image={ablum} sx={{ width: 151, border: 4 }} alt="Live from space album cover" />
        </Card>
```

Actually, I faced this problem a lot that I cannot control the flexbox size. Has anyone got an idea how I can push the photo to far right using something like `justifyContent: 'flex-end'`? But before that, I believes I need to fix the flexbox size first. Feel free to leave a comment if you got an idea. Thanks.

Comment: I added a sx = {{ ml: 'auto' }} in the CardMedia component, it automatically pushed the image to the right side. But my question remained, how to control the flexbox? If you have any idea feel free to drop a comment, appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at following link to get more about flex box!
css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

In your case you can add `flexGrow: 1` to the first Box (CardContent wrapper).